# Error 400 when trying to add new contact via SendGrid Contacts API

Tags: php, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

Whenever I attempt to add a new contact via the API I get a 400 error.

Here's my code so far:

```php
        $emails = json_decode('{
            "list_ids": [
                "LIST_ID_HERE",
            ],
            "contacts": [
                {
                    "email": "example@example.com",
                }
            ]
        }');
        $sendgrid = new SendGrid(getenv('SENDGRID_API_KEY'));
        try {
            $response = $sendgrid->client->marketing()->contacts()->put($emails);;
            print $response->statusCode();
            print_r($response->headers());
            print $response->body();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo 'Caught exception: '. $e->getMessage() ."\n";
        }
```

I've tried it with and without the `list_ids`, but I get the same response. Here's the exact output from this code:

```
400Array ( [0] => HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request [1] => Server: nginx [2] => Date: Sun, 28 Aug 2022 02:41:11 GMT [3] => Content-Type: application/json [4] => Content-Length: 50 [5] => Connection: keep-alive [6] => x-amzn-requestid: 919d1e69-9f8e-46a0-b2d2-72dcca1753c3 [7] => access-control-allow-origin: * [8] => access-control-allow-headers: AUTHORIZATION, Content-Type, On-behalf-of, x-sg-elas-acl, X-Recaptcha, X-Request-Source [9] => x-amz-apigw-id: XjZXMHBWPHcF_pQ= [10] => access-control-allow-methods: PUT,OPTIONS,DELETE,OPTIONS [11] => access-control-expose-headers: Link, Location [12] => x-amzn-trace-id: Root=1-630ad5c7-5825916353f578786cb7c908;Sampled=0 [13] => x-envoy-upstream-service-time: 105 [14] => referrer-policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin [15] => x-content-type-options: nosniff [16] => x-ratelimit-limit: 200 [17] => x-ratelimit-remaining: 199 [18] => x-ratelimit-reset: 49 [19] => [20] => ) {"errors":[{"field":"","message":"invalid JSON"}]}
```

I'm assuming I'm doing something wrong, but most of this code was copied directly from the SendGrid API documentation.

I'd appreciate any help, I'm just trying to get this working before we go live next week. I'd hate to have to leave this feature out of the production build.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your JSON isn't valid. JSON doesn't handle trailing commas, so your commas after the list ID and after the email address make this invalid. Sadly, `json_decode` doesn't throw an error when given invalid JSON, it just returns `null`.

Try this:

```php
        $emails = json_decode('{
            "list_ids": [
                "LIST_ID_HERE"
            ],
            "contacts": [
                {
                    "email": "example@example.com"
                }
            ]
        }');
```

Comment: Holy cow, figures it'd be something that simple. The documentation had the comma (since it included some entries after the emails), so it threw me off. I tend to leave the commas on in my code elsewhere, so it didn't even occur to me that JSON didn't handle the comma. Thanks for that!